# Aggregate with trimmed means in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I am trying to aggregate data like this in R:

```
df = data.frame(c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c"))
colnames(df) = "f"
set.seed(10)
df$e = rnorm(13,20,5)

    f   e
1   a   20.09373
2   a   19.07874
3   a   13.14335
4   a   17.00416
5   a   21.47273
6   b   21.94897
7   b   13.95962
8   b   18.18162
9   b   11.86664
10  b   18.71761
11  c   25.50890
12  c   23.77891
13  c   18.80883
```

Which I would like to aggregate by the column *f* and have a **trimmed mean** of *e* for each unique *f* type (i.e. produce 3 rows of data).

I tried:

```
df2=data.frame(0) 
df2=aggregate(df$e, by = "f",mean(df$e, trim=0.1))
```

got the following error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'mean(df$e, trim = 0.1)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Tried a few searches online and came up empty. My actual data consists of around 30 values of *e* per *f* so I am not concerned that `trim=0.1` won't actually trim the means in the example (because no points lie outside of the upper and lower 5th percentile) it will with the real data, this is just to get the aggregate function working as intended. Thanks!

Comment: FYI if you run `mean(df$e, trim = 0.1)` you'll see that the result is't a function, character or symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
df2=aggregate(e~f,data=df,mean,trim=0.1)
  f        e
1 a 18.15854
2 b 16.93489
3 c 22.69888
```

Function to use for calculation in this case can be given just by its name, for example, `mean`, and additional parameters needed for that function are set after comma.